# Cython: why is size_t faster than int?

Tags: python, performance, types, cython

Changing certain Cython variables from type `int` to type `size_t` can significantly reduce some functions times (~30%), but I do not understand why.

For example:

```
cimport numpy as cnp
import numpy as np

def sum_int(cnp.int64_t[::1] A):
    cdef unsigned long s = 0
    cdef int k
    for k in xrange(A.shape[0]):
        s += A[k]
    return s

def sum_size_t(cnp.int64_t[::1] A):
    cdef unsigned long s = 0
    cdef size_t k
    for k in xrange(A.shape[0]):
        s += A[k]
    return s

a = np.array(range(1000000))
```

And the timing results:

```
In [17]: %timeit sum_int(a)   
1000 loops, best of 3: 652 µs per loop

In [18]: %timeit sum_size_t(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 427 µs per loop
```

I am new to Cython, and know Fortran better than C. Help me out. What is the important difference between these two variable types that causes such a performance difference? What is it that I don't grok about Cython?

Comment: have you checked the generated assembly?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I tried to look at the generated C code, but almost went blind. I'm sure it's highly optimized, but as I'm more of a Fortran guy the auto-generated C was pretty hard to read.

Comment: You're taking an array of `int64_t`. Why not use `int64_t` for your accumulator?

Comment: @user2357112 lol. Well, I guess I thought adding a million numbers might overflow a 64-bit int. Sloppy. BUT, it won't change the result. The accumulator type doesn't change between the two examples.

Comment: Isn't `size_t` implicitly unsigned ? As you are using your variable `k` in a loop I guess it is optimized if you use size_t or an unsigned int as cython doc reports *"range() is C optimized when the index value has been declared by cdef, for example"*. So it is known the unsigned value that you use later as an indexer for `A` will never be negative (and it should allow you to turn the `wraparound` and the `boundscheck` parameters to `False`, as your are safely looping within the bounds of your array, and maybe have more performance) ?

Comment: @mgc Oh! I just tested that. That's really close to it. I just tried again using `unsigned int` instead of `int` and got *almost* all the way to the speed of `size_t`. Still, only like 80% of the way there though.  So close!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'd likely have to do a line by line profiling to find out exactly, but one thing stands out to me from the produced C file: `int` version is checked for wraparound to negative numbers, `size_t` is assumed ok.

In the int loop: (`t_3` is assigned from `k`, they're the same type)

```
if (__pyx_t_3 < 0) {
  __pyx_t_3 += __pyx_v_A.shape[0];
  if (unlikely(__pyx_t_3 < 0)) __pyx_t_4 = 0;
} else if (unlikely(__pyx_t_3 >= __pyx_v_A.shape[0])) __pyx_t_4 = 0;
```

In the size_t loop:

```
if (unlikely(__pyx_t_3 >= (size_t)__pyx_v_A.shape[0])) __pyx_t_4 = 0;
```

So no wraparound test is needed because `size_t` is unsigned and guaranteed not to wrap around when indexing items in memory. The rest is virtually the same.

Update: regarding your `unsigned int` results - what's your size of int and size_t? Any chance they're different size, causing the change? In my case the C code for uint and size_t is identical. (since size_t is unsigned and specifically unsigned int on this system)

Comment: Okay, I did some time testing and found that if I use an "unsigned int" and turn off wrap-around testing with a decorator, as you suggest above, I get back the performance of "size_t". So, if you add a note that "size_t" is unsigned, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Always turn off bounds check and wrap-around, once you know what you are doing... I didn't know using size_t would imply that automatically.

Answer (score 5):

On a 64 bit system there seem to be two reasons:

1. Use an unsigned integer for the loop:

   ```
   %%cython

   cimport numpy as cnp
   import numpy as np

   def sum_int_unsigned(cnp.int64_t[::1] A):
       cdef unsigned long s = 0
       cdef unsigned k
       for k in xrange(A.shape[0]):
           s += A[k]
       return s
   ```
2. Use a `long` instead of an `int`:

   ```
   %%cython

   cimport numpy as cnp
   import numpy as np

   def sum_int_unsigned_long(cnp.int64_t[::1] A):
       cdef unsigned long s = 0
       cdef unsigned long k
       for k in xrange(A.shape[0]):
           s += A[k]
       return s
   ```

Timings:

```
%timeit sum_int(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.52 ms per loop

%timeit sum_size_t(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 671 µs per loop
```

Using `unsigned` brings us half way:

```
%timeit sum_int_unsigned(a) 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.09 ms per loop
```

Using `long` accounts for the rest:

```
%timeit sum_int_unsigned_long(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 648 µs per loop
```