# What does ob_size reprensents in the structure of long integer?

Tags: python, cpython

The integer (long) type definition effectively looks like this (once the C macros are expanded):

```
struct _longobject {
  long ob_refcnt;
  PyTypeObject *ob_type;
  size_t ob_size;
  uint32_t ob_digit[1];
  };
```

Here, what does ob_size mean and what its value represents?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932600/cython-why-is-size-t-faster-than-int not the complete answer but here is a discussion of cython size_t implementation differences.

Comment: Did you look at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/longintrepr.h)? Short version: the absolute value of `ob_size` is the number of 30-bit or 15-bit (depending on the build) digits; the sign of `ob_size` is the sign of the integer.

Comment: (I removed the NumPy and Pandas tags; they're not relevant here - this is a question about pure CPython, and the NumPy integer types have their own implementation that doesn't need an `ob_size` field.)

Comment: I'm still not able to understand!

Answer (score 2):

Python `_longobject` (A.K.A. `int`) is variable size and that is the standard python header for variable objects. From [object.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h):

```
/* PyObject_VAR_HEAD defines the initial segment of all variable-size
 * container objects.  These end with a declaration of an array with 1
 * element, but enough space is malloc'ed so that the array actually
 * has room for ob_size elements.  Note that ob_size is an element count,
 * not necessarily a byte count.
 */
```

`_longobject` is allocated on the heap in a memory block large enough to hold `long ob_digit[ob_size]` long integers.

Comment: So value of the object is stored in ob_digit[ob_size], but why they are stored in an array as it is a single value?

Comment: @SachinSharma - interestingly, its not. Python integers can grow to arbitrary size. If you create an integer that overflows `ob_digit[1]`, python allocates larger space to make it fit.

Comment: Suppose that the size of array is 2. Then, how a big value will be stored? Will the half binary representation of the number be stored in one block and remaining on the other or there is another way to store the values?

Comment: @SachinSharma: Pretty much, yes: the binary representation of the absolute value of the number is broken into 30-bit blocks, and one of those 30-bit blocks is stored in each `uint32_t` "digit". The first digit (`x->ob_digit[0]`) has the least significant 30 bits; the next digit has bits 30 through 59, and so on. So a 128-bit number would need array of 5 "digits". It's just the usual base system for representing an integer, except that the base here is `2^30`. (Technical note: some builds/platforms might use 15-bit digits rather than 30-bit.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson - Thanks for the details.

Comment: Adding to @MarkDickinson, python includes optimizations for small integers between -5 and 255, plus integers of 30 bits or less that fit into one digit. Otherwise its your basic base1073741824 math.